# page numbering in tabel of contents

Tags: latex, tableofcontents, overleaf, texstudio

The table of contents has to be renumbered. I am using a template from overleaf. I have seen thorough old posts but none have helped. The roman numeral numbering starts right from the dedication and stops at publications. I need the roman numerals to start from the abstract and stop at publications and the remaining table of contents to remain intact.

I have tried changing the

```
\begin{romanpages}
```

command to different places but doesn't work.

MWE of my code from overleaf is given below

`PhDthesis.cls` has the following

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{PhDthesis}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\documentclass{0_ClassFiles/PhDthesis}

\begin{document}
    
    \onehalfspacing
    
        
        \include{2_Title/title}
        \makethesistitle

        
        \begin{romanpages}
        %%%% ---------------  Uncomment in Final version ---------------
        \phantomsection
        \include{3_Dedication/Dedication}

        
        \phantomsection
        \include{6_Declaration/Declaration}

        
        \phantomsection
        \include{5_Certificate/Certificate}

        
        \phantomsection
        \include{7_Acknowledgement/Acknowledgement}

        
        \phantomsection
        \include{8_Abstract/Abstract}

        \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
        \tableofcontents

        
        \newcommand{\figname}{List of Figures}

    
        \phantomsection
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\figname}
        \listoffigures

        
        \newcommand{\tabname}{List of Tables}
        \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries \tabname}
        \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries \tabname}
    
        \phantomsection
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tabname}
        \listoftables

        
    \phantomsection
    \include{12_Publication/Publication}


    \end{romanpages}

    
    \include{10a_Introduction/Introduction} 
    \include{10b_Chapter2/Chapter2}% Related Work
    \include{10c_Chapter3/Chapter3}
    \include{10d_Chapter4/Chapter4}
    \include{10e_Chapter5/Chapter5}
    \include{10z_Conclusions/Conclusions}   
    

    
    \bibliographystyle{agsm}
    %\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}   
    \renewcommand\bibname{Bibliography}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries Bibliography}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries Bibliography}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
    \bibliography{scopus}

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries Appendices}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
    \include{11_Appendices/Appendices}

    
    \onehalfspacing

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre] which we can compile without all the local files on your computer we don't have access to?

Comment: Is it not possible to put in some dummy text and compile it. I am not sure how to remove / add in local files from overleaf.

Comment: Why is dummy text not possible? If the problem is really related to loading external files, you could create them with the `filecontents` environment